# a JavaScript library for drawing intractable shapes

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, frameworks

I'm looking for a JavaScript library/framework I can use for drawing circles, rectangles, rulers and to be able to interact with them (rotate/resize) using both an API and the UI (so the user can do it as well).

I'm looking for an HTML5 compatible solution, SVG is not an option for me.

Happy with a jquery plugin, if there is anything like that.

I found Paper and it seems that it can draw all shapes and I guess that with some efforts I can do a ruler there, but I didn't find how to interact with the objects it draws.

Would be more than happy if anyone can give me any tip!  :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinetic is pretty solid and its open

http://kineticjs.com/

good tutourial site to get you started

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-rect-tutorial/

EaselJS is more corporate...
http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS